# jQuery creating duplicate variable

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a custom jQuery lightbox solution for a client. I'm using the data attribute to create relational images (the same as fancybox would do). On close of the lightbox, I reset the variables so that my index will be 0 next time I open a gallery (this determines whether or not to show the previous / next buttons).

Strangely, the next time I open a gallery and click the next icon, the console shows me 2 values for the variable currentIndex. and on closing it and opening a third gallery, it shows me 3 values for the variable currentIndex.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function centerGalleryOverlay(){
        var top = ($('.image-container').height() / 2).toFixed() ;
        $('.image-container').css('marginTop', '-' + top + 'px');

        var left = ($('.image-container').width() / 2).toFixed() ;
        $('.image-container').css('marginLeft', '-' + left + 'px'); 
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var galleryTitle = null;

        $('.cm-gallery').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            galleryTitle = $(this).data('gallery');


            $('.gallery-overlay .image-container img').attr( 'src', $(this).attr('href') );
            $('.gallery-overlay').fadeIn(500);

            centerGalleryOverlay();

            var galleryItems = null;
            galleryItems = [];

            $('.cm-gallery').each(function(){
                if($(this).data('gallery') == galleryTitle){
                    galleryItems.push($(this).attr('href')) 
                }
            });

            var currentIndex = null;
            currentIndex = 0;

            if(galleryItems.length > 0){
                $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-next').show();
            }

            $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-next').click(function(){
                currentIndex = currentIndex + 1;
                console.log(currentIndex);

                if(currentIndex >= (galleryItems.length - 1) ){
                    $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-next').hide();
                }

                $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-prev').show();
                $('.gallery-overlay .image-container img').attr( 'src', galleryItems[currentIndex] );   

            })

            $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-prev').click(function(){
                currentIndex = currentIndex - 1;
                console.log(currentIndex);
                if(currentIndex <= 0 ){
                    $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-prev').hide();
                }

                $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-next').show();
                $('.gallery-overlay .image-container img').attr( 'src', galleryItems[currentIndex] );   

            })
        })

        $('.gallery-overlay .gallery-close').click(function(){
            $('.gallery-overlay').hide();

            galleryItems = null;
            currentIndex = null;
            galleryTitle = null;
        });

    })


</script>
```

Comment: Please paste the relevant code - external links will make your question irrelevant as soon as the destination changes.

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: apologies, have included source here now

Answer (score 1):

You are binding new click handlers every time you click on `.cm-gallery`

```
$('.cm-gallery').click(function(e){
    /* ... */

    $('.gallery-overlay .image-container .gallery-next').click(function(){
```

So the first time you click, the next button has 1 click handler, the 2nd time 2 click handlers, etc.

You should move the `click` handler outside of the other click handler so the handlers are only attached once.